# objective-c send url according to my menu select

Tags: objective-c, iphone, json, uitableview, ios9.1

i have a custom UItableView . i am loading data from a API and my main view are 
i am loading  data from a API .
[image]

My problem is,i have a left-side menu, i want to send a url when user select any menu acoording to select menu view will load.
[image]

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

```
if(indexPath.row ==0){
    appdataModel.newsApiUrl = homePagesUrl;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];

    ContactsTableViewController *vc = [[ContactsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:contView animated:YES];

}else if (indexPath.row ==1){
    appdataModel.newsApiUrl = jatioNews;

    NSLog(@"here  1 :%@",appdataModel.newsApiUrl);
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];
    ContactsTableViewController *vc = [[ContactsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:contView animated:YES];
}
else if (indexPath.row ==2){
    appdataModel.newsApiUrl = jatioNews;

    NSLog(@"here  1 :%@",appdataModel.newsApiUrl);
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];
        ContactsTableViewController *vc = [[ContactsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:contView animated:YES];
}
```

}

```
#define homePagesNews @"http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/topnews"
#define jatioNews @"http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/categorynews/4"
```

here my api link . if user select Home-menu then view will load form `homePagesNews API` else user select second menu then view will from `jatioNews API`

from this code i am getting data

-(void)GetHomePageData{

```
NSString *urlString   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
NSURL *url            = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *GETReply      = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves|| NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

}

now i want when user select menu may home-menu or second-menu or third-menu according to user select `url` link will change and view will load in my `ContactsTableViewController`

my  ContactsTableViewController `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appdataModel = [AppDataModel getInstance]; 
    appdataModel.newsApiUrl = homePagesUrl;

     /**** for left side menu ***/

    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController )
    {
        [self.sideBarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
        [self.sideBarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }

     /**** for Contractview***/
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contacts" ofType:@"plist"];
    contactsArray  = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile :path];
    [self GetHomePageData];

    [self.newsDataTableView reloadData];

}
```

some can tell me how can i solve my problem ... Thanks

Comment: So what you're really asking is how to get the URL into the `ContactsTableViewController` instance?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes .. please check my code again .i updated

Comment: Add an `url` property to the view controller and set it?  There is lots of repeated code in that method that can be cut down to something like 10 lines.

Comment: @trojanfoe would kindly edit and help me ourt how i solve my problem . that would be great help for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `url` property to `ContactsTableViewController`:

```
@interface ContactsTableViewController : UIViewController
@property NSURL *url;
...
@end
```

and in its `viewDidLoad` method you can load the data using whatever method you are using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
  dataTaskWithURL:self.url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // Whatever
    }];
```

Then set the URL from the tableview delegate method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.row ==0){
        appdataModel.newsApiUrl = homePagesUrl;
    } else {
        appdataModel.newsApiUrl = jatioNews;
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];

    ContactsTableViewController *vc = [[ContactsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.url = [NSURL URLWithString:appdataModel.newsApiUrl];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan Are you seeing the correct URL in the `viewDidLoad` method (set a breakpoint)?